# IE10 change the Style of the TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

when i change the display styleof the TR and run the application on IE10 
there's a change in this style, and i checked css's files and there's no skin file

here's what i wrote in the code :

```
<tr id="trIADMem" style="visibility:hidden" height="20"  runat="server">
```

and that's what i found in the browser developer tools panel :

```
<tr height="20" id="trIADMem" style="display: block;">
```

with acknowledge there's other TR's worked correctly 
what i wrote in the code :

```
<tr id="trApproverComments" style="visibility:visible" height="20"  runat="server">
```

that's what i found in the browser developer tools panel :

```
<tr height="20" id="trApproverComments" style="visibility: visible;">
```

could you tell me where's the wrong or am i missed any thing ?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Something else is going on, you need to post more code. What are you doing with `trIADMem` in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery to set its style? To be more specific, are you using toggle method to do that?

Since the `style="visibility:hidden"` are changed to `style="display: block;`, so I think here is wrong, try to set `style="visibility:visible"` by jQuery css like:

```
$(selector).css("visibility","visible");
```